# Mat-Select is not showing any options whenever I navigate away

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a mat-select element

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline">
  <mat-select multiple>
   <mat-option value="Option1">Option 1</mat-option>
   <mat-option value="Option2">Option 2</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

that is working fine when I navigate to the component for the first time.
[image]

However, if I navigate away, for example to http://localhost:7005/#/pages/chat, and then I navigate back to the network component, the dropdown is not showing options anymore
[image]

and I am getting the following errors

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'appendChild')
    at NbOverlayContainerAdapter._createContainer (index.js:952:1)
    at NbOverlayContainerAdapter.getContainerElement (overlay.js:714:1)
    at Overlay._createHostElement (overlay.js:2606:1)
    at Overlay.create (overlay.js:2573:1)
    at CdkConnectedOverlay._createOverlay (overlay.js:2810:1)
    at CdkConnectedOverlay._attachOverlay (overlay.js:2884:1)
    at CdkConnectedOverlay.ngOnChanges (overlay.js:2802:1)
    at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (core.js:21760:1)
    at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.js:30689:1)
    at checkAndUpdateNode (core.js:30651:1)

ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'updateSize')
    at CdkConnectedOverlay.ngOnChanges (overlay.js:2791:1)
    at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (core.js:21760:1)
    at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.js:30689:1)
    at checkAndUpdateNode (core.js:30651:1)
    at prodCheckAndUpdateNode (core.js:31193:1)
    at Object.updateDirectives (index.d.ts.MatSelect.html:17:1)
    at Object.updateDirectives (core.js:30978:1)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:30633:1)
    at callViewAction (core.js:30874:1)
    at execComponentViewsAction (core.js:30816:1)
```

I get the first error the first time I click on the dropdown after I navigate back to the network component, and the second error I receive the subsequent times I click on the dropdown.

As requested here is the code of the NetworkComponent:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-network',
    templateUrl: './network.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./network.component.scss'],
})
export class NetworkComponent {}
```

Comment: please provide code in your ts file

Comment: please provide code us